# adjectif + de/à + infinitif

Tags: choix-de-mot

Existe-t-il une règle permettant de savoir s'il faut utiliser *de* ou *à* dans une structure *adjectif + de/à + infinitif* ?

> Déterminer s'il faut mettre à ou de est difficile ***à*** dire.

Pourquoi est-ce *à* ?

> C'est difficile ***de*** déterminer s'il faut mettre à ou de.

Pourquoi est-ce de ?

Cela laisse penser que la structure sémantique détermine la règle. Pourtant :

> C'est important ***de*** choisir.
>
> C'est difficile ***à*** voir.

Comment: Bonne question, je pense que ça à voir avec le fait qu'il y ait un objet implicite ou pas. On dit "**quelque chose*** *est difficile à voir*", mais si il n'y a pas d'objet on utiliserait *de* : "*Avec ce brouillard, c'est difficile de voir devant soi*". Dans ton exemple *choisir* n'a pas d'objet implicite. (*Par "objet implicite" je veux dire qu'un verbe qui peut être transitif est utilisé de manière intransitive, comme "choisir" dans ton exemple*)